# Nav overflow on 15 inch

Tags: html, css

I am developing a site:

www.alexisparkinn.com

When I view the site on a laptop with a 15inch screen my nav bar wraps to a new line and I don't know why it is doing this.  I can also get this error to happen when I zoom out of a webpage in any browser.  I'm confused to why this is happening.

I don't know where to look either, any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The physical dimensions of the screen is irrelevant. What matters is the browser, the resolution you're running at, and (if changed) how many DPI the OS is using. If you provide those details, it will be a lot easier to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Getting it on zoom is definitely strange. That should scale.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  How can I figure out the DPI (dots per inch)?  I am running on a windows machine.  Each time I found the error it was on a windows laptop with a 15 inch screen but I am able to duplicate the error by zooming out in any browser.  let me know what else I need to do, Thanks!

Comment: You probably have zoom text only enabled in browser, that is only way to reproduce what you say. And that is zoom in, not out.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you don't know about the DPI, and you haven't switched on large fonts, then you are most likely running with the default, and then that doesn't really influence the result (because most people are running with the default). The browser is the most important piece of information, followed by the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you are referring to (viewed in Firefox 4, no zoom):

[image: Screenshot of op's site in Firefox 4]

It looks to me like you're not giving enough space for the amount of links you want, so the `<li>` just wrap to the next line, breaking your layout. I'd suggest merging a few links or looking into implementing some kind of drop down menu system.

This isn't really a problem with DPI or your screen resolution, as all that scales: your page elements should always be in proportion with each other, even if they're not the same size on different screens.